# Parsing, matching and keywords

Tags: rascal

I am working with the Java15 grammar and have a couple questions about how Rascal's parser works and why some things aren't working. Given a concrete syntax:

```
module tests::Concrete

start syntax CompilationUnit =
    compilationUnit: TypeDec* LAYOUTLIST
    ;

syntax TypeDec =
    ClassDec
    ;

syntax ClassDec =
    \class: ClassDecHead ClassBody
    ;

syntax ClassDecHead =
    "class" Id
    ;

syntax ClassBody =
    "{" ClassBodyDec* "}"
    ;

syntax ClassBodyDec =
    ClassMemberDec
    ;

syntax ClassMemberDec =
    MethodDec
    ;

syntax MethodDec =
    \method: MethodDecHead
    ;

syntax MethodDecHead =
    ResultType Id
    ;

syntax ResultType =
    \void: "void"
    ;

syntax Id =
    \id: [A-Z_a-z] !<< ID \ IDKeywords !>> [0-9A-Z_a-z]
    ;

keyword Keyword =
    "void"
    ;

keyword IDKeywords =
    "null"
    | Keyword
    ;

lexical LAYOUT =
    [\t-\n \a0C-\a0D \ ]
    ;

lexical ID =
    [A-Z_a-z] [0-9A-Z_a-z]*
    ;

layout LAYOUTLIST  =
    LAYOUT* !>> [\t-\n \a0C-\a0D \ ] !>> (  [/]  [*]  ) !>> (  [/]  [/]  ) !>> "/*" !>> "//"
    ;
```

an AST definition:

```
module tests::Abstract

data Declaration =
    \compilationUnit(list[Declaration] body)
   | \package(ID name)
   | \import(ID name)
   | \class(ID name, list[Declaration] body)
   | \method(Type ret, ID name)
             ;

data Type =
    \void()
    ;

data ID =
    \id(str id)
    ;
```

and a driver to load files:

```
module tests::Load

import Prelude;
import tests::Concrete;
import tests::Abstract;

public Declaration load(loc l) = implode(#Declaration, parse(#CompilationUnit, l));
```

I'm finding some oddities in what is actually working and what isn't. If I take the program:

```
class A {

}
```

This parses as expected into: `compilationUnit([ class(id("A"),[]) ])`
But parsing and constructing AST nodes for methods inside of the class is proving to be a bit hairy. Given the program:

```
class A {
    void f
}
```

this produces a `"Cannot find a constructor for Declaration"` error. If I modify the syntax to be:

```
syntax MethodDecHead =
    ResultType
    ;
```

The AST to be:

```
| \method(Type ret)
```

I'm able to get the tree I would expect: `compilationUnit([class(id("A"),[method(void())])])`

I'm having a lot of confusion about what's going on here, how keywords are handled and what's causing this behaviour.

In addition to this if I don't add the `LAYOUTLIST` to the end of the `start syntax` production I get a `ParseError` anytime I try to read from a file.

Comment: Might as well paste the whole example files in here. Seem small enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The production rule of `ClassDec` is not compatible with the AST node `class`.
Changing it to:

`syntax ClassDec =
    \class: "class" Id "{" ClassBodyDec* "}"
    ;`

Makes it more regular and isomorphic with the AST node `class(ID name, list[Declaration])`

However: the names should always correspond, so I'd suggest changing `ID` to `Id` in the grammar. Further, your AST node expects `Declaration`s, but in the grammar you have `ClassBodyDec`s.

The general rules for `implode` are:

- Non-terminal corresponds to ADT type
- Production label corresponds to ADT constructor
- Keywords, operators, layout etc. is skipped.
- Unlabeled lexical productions map to primitives (str, int, real).
- Labeled lexicals can map to constructors if you want: `lexical Id = id: [a-z]+`, can map to `data Id = id(str x)`;
- If you don't label context-free productions, `implode` "looks over them": so if I had `syntax A = B; syntax B = cons: "bla"`, then I can use the ADT: `data A = cons()`.

(These rules are documented in Parsetree.rsc, https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/blob/master/src/org/rascalmpl/library/ParseTree.rsc)

Comment: Perfect, thanks @Tijs. I've got some stuff working and I think I have the tools now to push forward and hopefully figure out the rest :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the expert on `implode` so I leave that for now, but the LAYOUTLIST thing is due to the way `parse` is called.

Every `start` non-terminal defined by `start Something =` produces two types, namely:
   * the non-terminal itself `Something` and 
   * a wrapper non-terminal named `start[Something]`.

The wrapper is automatically/implicitly defined by this:

```
syntax start[Something] = LAYOUTLIST before Something top LAYOUTLIST after;
```

So, if you want to have whitespace and comments before and after your program you call parse like so:

```
parse(#start[Something], yourLocation)
```

And if you are not interested in keeping the comments or whitespace for later, then you could project out the top tree like so:

```
Something mySomething = parse(#start[Something], myLocation).top;
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Where can I look / who should I contact for more information on `implode`. I have a suspicion this is caused by how the layout, ids and keywords are interacting with the grammar.